# Azure Function 2.0 stuck until I open it in the portal?

Tags: function, azure, .net-core, kudu

I have an Azure Function with a TimerTrigger written in .NET Core, so it uses the beta runtime (a.k.a. "Functions 2.x").

When I have the function run locally in the function host all works fine, even the `RunOnStartup` flag seems to be honored, but when I deploy the function to Azure (which I do with PowerShell and the Kudu REST Api), the function seems to "sleep" until I manually open it in the portal, i.e. the TimerTrigger does not fire, and neither does it run right away as indicated by the `RunOnStartup` flag.

I have analyzed this using the logstream feature.
The function is on a classic appservice plan (S1 SKU) and is set to "always on".

Anyone have any pointers as to whats going on? This is the signature of the function:

```
[FunctionName("MyTimeTriggerFct)]
public static async Task Run(
    [TimerTrigger("0 */3 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true, UseMonitor = false)]
    TimerInfo myTimer,
    ILogger log,
    ExecutionContext context)
    {
        //...
    }
```

Comment: It's odd if you have Always On enabled. Can you share your function app name (that's the **app** name, not function name!), either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately)?

Comment: 2018-06-07T17:54:00.006 [Information] Executing [FctName] (Reason='Timer fired at 2018-06-07T17:54:00.0060980+00:00', Id=d787ad9e-ea8f-47be-bab4-46bdcecc0713)

region is westeurope

Comment: I do see something odd with the Always On requests. Will need to dig deeper.

Comment: Also, could you provide a sample UTC time during which your timer trigger was supposed to have fired and did not?

Comment: @DavidEbbo whats the easiest way of finding out the schedule?

Comment: @PaulLatzelsperger not quite sure I understand your question. The schedule is whatever you set on your Function (e.g. 3 minutes in the code above). But we need to know a time when it wasn't working to investigate.

Comment: yeah I get that, and in this case it's "every 3 minutes", but when do those three minutes "start"? Or: how do I find out the _exact UTC time_ when the function should run? As the `RunOnStartup` flag seems to be ignored, I naively assume there is some kind of global scheduling, such as e.g. 09:00:00, 09:03:00, 09:06:00 and so on.

Comment: Oh and by the way I just discovered, that it's the same for a ServiceBus-triggered Function: it also only executes after having clicked on it in the portal. ID is `f1f4a1d8-5eee-4b53-a019-44b17ccf27a1` and (after having clicked on it) it ran at `2018-06-11T09:03:02.136`